# Internal microphone only works with headset plugged in

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

When my headset is plugged in, microphone works well

Ubuntu sounds settings

[image: Ubuntu sounds settings]

But when I plug it out, internal microphone does not detect any sound.. I tried some solutions on severals posts, but nothing seems to work.. I'm on ubuntu 19.10 on HP laptop

Here's the output when I run pulseaudio. Thanks !

pusleaudio result

[image: pusleaudio result]

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing and running pavucontrol. It's a tool that allows you to control the playback, **input devices** (which probably is what you're looking for), output devices and much more.

- Open terminal and enter the following command:

> sudo apt install pavucontrol

- You can now open it from Dash. Go to **Input Devices** tab and from
  there, you can choose the port which the sound will be captured by.
  When you hit this option, a list of microphones (both internal and
  plugged) will be shown, allowing you to choose the one of your
  desire.

[image]

Maybe, using pavucontrol will allow you to force your system to choose corretly the input device at the right time when you plug and unplug your headphone. Give it a try and see if that works. Besides, you will have much more control of what's happening with the sound of your system using this tool.